# Error Code: 3734. Failed to add the foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

compre un curso de SQL y la verdad es que estoy teniendo problemas constantemente, se esta haciendo cuesta arriba ya que al seguirlo siempre a la hora de compilar me tira errores. :(
el ejercicio consta en crear una base de datos para un hospital.

- Creo las tablas tal cual están en el video pero al llegar a medico_has_especialidad me figura el siguiente error :

> Error Code: 3734. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'id' for constraint 'especialidad_id' in the referenced table 'especialidad'

la tabla especialidad dicta lo siguiente :

```
> CREATE TABLE especialidad(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_especialidad VARCHAR (45)
);
```

comparto una foto para que puedan tener una idea mas general del proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código mínimo para replicar y ver el problema va como texto, lee [ask]

Comment: Por qué la etiqueta sql server?

Comment: Saludos. Te indica que la tabla `especialidad` no tiene el campo `id`; verifica el nombre de la columna.

Comment: Si el código del curso está mal, deberíás pedirle la corrección a quien lo publica. Digo yo, que el cliente siempre tiene la razón. Ahora, que puedes corregirlo tú mismo con lo que te han comentado, pues también

Answer (score 1):

La solución a tu problema es que estas tratando de crear una referencia a una tabla donde el id de referencia es inexistente

`CONSTRAINT NombreADar  FOREIGN KEY (ElCampoDondeQuieresTomarLaReferencia)  REFERENCES nombreDeLaTablaYaCreada(CualSeraElIdParaLlamarALaTabla)`

Si la referencia (en este caso el id) es inexistente te va arrojar el error 3734

Para ver las tablas creadas y verificar que todo este bien puedes colocar

```
DESCRIBE nombreDeLaTabla;
```

Si existe, te va a mostrar como se estructura la tabla, de lo contrario te va arrojar un error diciendo que la tabla no existe.
Por ende debes crear primero la tabla para luego hacer la referencia